# SignalR Ping request

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

We have an application which uses SignalR hubs but the hubs location is in a different server not in the application server.
All the signalR ping requests from the application are going to application server, how to make ping requests to hit the signalR server (different hub server).

The question is about ping url when the hub location is in a different server.

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a SignalR hub connection to work cross-domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875228/how-do-i-get-a-signalr-hub-connection-to-work-cross-domain)

Comment: No i dont think it is duplicate, Thanks for the reply!